# 3DES Feasibility and Security

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, modes-of-operation, 3des

Questions are as following:

1. Is 3DES still **feasible (in terms of security and
   performance)** to use?
2. Is 3DES safe to use in **ECB** mode?
3. Every time on giving the same input (plain text) to encrypt via 3DES
   results same output (cipher text). What would the reason be for
   that?  For example: Every time I gave input plain text **'wealth'**
   the output generated was **'VxDfWEQA'**. Or is that even possible?
4. If one would want to discourage a company to not to use 3DES with
   cipher mode **ECB** and padding **PKCS7** what would that reason
   would be and why?
5. If a company/entity still insists to use 3DES. What configuration
   would be the most suitable to be set for it e.g. cipher mode and
   padding.

Would like to have the answer of third question considering all possible scenario's if applicable e.g. considering all 3 **keys** for 3DES were same.

Comment: Point 3 does not sound as truthful: there's one chance against >340000 that a DES ciphertext is 8 letters.

Comment: @fgrieu, I have updated the question.

Comment: 1. slow 2. no; ECB is ECB, 3. because ECB. 4. see wikipedia on modes of opreations, 5. depend on the what to enrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is 3DES still feasible (in terms of security and performance) to use?

3DES is *very* slow except if you have specialised hardware, so it at most wins in speed on legacy hardware that has dedicated DES circuitry but no AES circuitry. If no specialised hardware is available, AES or most other modern lightweight ciphers will be significantly faster.

3DES also has a very small block size, meaning it can start leaking data after just a few GB of encrypted data, see also [Sweet32](https://sweet32.info/). Additionally the 112-bit key is considered to be quite short these days even though technically still sufficient, but it could be too short for e.g. reasonable security against multi-target attacks.

> Is 3DES safe to use in ECB mode?

No block cipher is safe to be used in ECB mode, as you will always see which plaintext blocks appear multiple times. Additionally deterministic encryption (such as when ECB is used) *cannot* achieve security against chosen-plaintext attacks (a rather weak security notion).

> Every time on giving the same input (plain text) to encrypt via 3DES
>   results same output (cipher text). What would the reason be for that?
>   For example: Every time I gave input plain text 'wealth' the output
>   generated was 'VxDfWEQA'. Or is that even possible?

(3)DES is a deterministic function, so if you give it the same input (that is the same message-key pair) twice you will get the same output twice. Randomness usually is only brought into the picture when *using* the block cipher. Also note that the probability of getting an ASCII-text ciphertext is $(52/256)^8\approx 0.000002898$.

> If one would want to discourage a company to not to use 3DES with
>   cipher mode ECB and padding PKCS7 what would that reason would be and
>   why?

See (1) and (3).

> If a company/entity still insists to use 3DES. What configuration
>   would be the most suitable to be set for it e.g. cipher mode and
>   padding.

[EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) mode or if neither are an option CTR mode with a counting (context-dependent) IV and then a secure *message authentication code* (MAC) applied on the ciphertext (which is what CCM and EAX do). These modes require no padding.

Comment: Why CCM? It's quite inefficient, which is worse since 3DES is so slow.

Comment: @forest I didn't want to assume availability of something like SHA256 and GCM isn't applicable (at least I think the standard doesn't specify a standard polynomial for 64-bit?) which leaves us with CCM and EAX.

Comment: Or OCB or Poly1305.